# Is it possible to make gnome-screenshot save the image automatically without showing the confirmation dialog window?

Tags: gnome

Is it possible to make gnome-screenshot save the image automatically without showing the confirmation dialog window?

I make a lot of screenshots and it would be convenient if I did not have to confirm at every occasion.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following command in the terminal:

`gnome-screenshot -p -w -d 10 -f ~/Desktop/Screenshots/$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).png`

`man gnome-screenshot` tells us that

- `-p` includes the mouse pointer
- `-w` limits the region to the active window
- `-d` is used to add a time delay (in seconds) and that's useful if you want to capture stuff like drop-down menus.
- `-f` specifies the path and filename. I've provided a filename that incorporates a "time-stamp".

**Note**: if you want to select a particular area, use `-a` (for area):

```
gnome-screenshot -a -f ~/Desktop/Screenshots/$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).png
```

The cursor changes to cross-hairs. Drag diagonally across the desired area. You can't use `-d` when using `-a`.

You can also make a keyboard shortcut so that you don't need to open a terminal each time. To do so, first make a small script using a plain text editor. The contents of the script are:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

gnome-screenshot -a -f ~/Desktop/Screenshots/$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).png
```

Save the file as a plain text file with an informative name such as my-gnome-screenshot and put the file in `~/bin`. If you don't have such a folder, create one.

Then, using your file manager, right-click on the file, choose `properties` and set the file to be executable by owner. If you're comfortable with the terminal, just run `chmod +x ~/bin/my-gnome-screenshot`.

Now, use your desktop environment's keyboard shortcut editor/creator to assign a keyboard shortcut to your script.

Then, each time you want to take a screenshot, just press the relevant keyboard shortcut.

Depending on your desktop environment, creating a script may not be needed. In `Openbox` which is the default window manager of Lubuntu, one can simply edit the `rc.xml` (or `lubuntu-rc.xml`) file to contain this keybind (or whatever is suitable and available):

```
<keybind key="W-4">        # gnome-screenshot of selected ares
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>sh -c 'gnome-screenshot -p -a -f ~/Desktop/Screenshots/$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).png'</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

If you wish to create a `.desktop` file for launching the script instead of using the terminal or a keyboard shortcut, the procedure is similar to what is described in the answer to [Timestamp in Exec= line of .desktop file possible?](https://askubuntu.com/a/778889/248158).

Comment: It's almost good but I would still like to be able to define the input area with the mouse as usual. Like if I want a specific part of the screen. Is it possible to add that functionality to the one-liner?

Comment: I tried to do it the easy way and add it through System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts. It almost works, it does save to desktop but the date syntax might be wrong because every image is saved as $(date. This is what I used: gnome-screenshot -a -f ~/Desktop/Screenshots/$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).png

Comment: It worked, thanks. I just removed the ~ like so: sh -c 'gnome-screenshot -a -f /home/user/Desktop/$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).png'

Comment: Well done DK Bose. I might be using this tool a lot.