# Timestamp in Exec= line of .desktop file possible?

Tags: bash, .desktop

Lubuntu 16.04 - Openbox session

I can use the terminal to open a time-stamped file with `gedit`:

```
gedit ~/$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).txt
```

The command can also be used via a keyboard shortcut in Openbox.

```
<keybind key="W-4">        # gedit time-stamped file
  <action name="Execute"><command>sh -c 'gedit ~/$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).txt'</command></action>
</keybind>
```

But I can't do the same via the `Exec=` line of a `.desktop` file.

```
Exec=sh -c 'gedit ~/$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).txt'
```

just creates a file called `~/.txt`

So how do I get a .desktop file to do what I want?

Comment: I don't think the .desktop file can call sub-shell `$()` commands like that.  I think you need it to call another script that contains your sub-shell command for opening your file.

Comment: Sure I will do that.  =)

Comment: HI @DKBose .desktop files *can* run sub shells, since `Exec=/bin/bash -c "echo $(date) > ~/out.txt"` runs fine.  the `+%Y%m%d%H%M%S` seems to be the issue. still chewing on it.

Comment: I assume the first thing doesn't work because % is already used as command line arguments for exec in [.desktop files](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en#tb-exec-params)
It might be possible to escape them somehow, but the other solution seems alright. I would have added this as a comment, but my account here is new.

Comment: Hi @DKBose see my answer :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, .desktop files don't always call sub-shell `$()` commands the way we would like them to.  One way to do this that I have found would be to create another script that contains the sub-shell command to open the file like that.

The `Exec` line would look like:

```
Exec=/path/to/script
```

then your script file would contain the command to open your new file:

```
#!/bin/sh

gedit ~/$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).txt
```

the script would also have to be executable:

```
chmod +x /path/to/script
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @JacobVlijm Is the issue similar to what one sees in `cron` where certain characters (`%`?) need to be esacped?

Comment: @DKBose Might very well be, I am still fiddling around with it, and I think it should work. Subshells alone are no issue.

Comment: @JacobVlijm You are probably correct.  I have found that I like to avoid the sub-shell commands within files like these, much like in the `sources.list` file of apt you cannot replace the release name with `$(lsb_release -sc)` as that doesn't work either.  If you do figure it out, I would love to see how you did it.  :)

Comment: Hi Terrance, it works! See my answer...

Comment: @JacobVlijm try using `+\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S` then it should work.

Comment: @Videonauth I know, that's how it is escaped from cron, that was one of my many attempts, unfortunately no luck... I will keep looking however, I am pretty sure there is a way.

Answer (score 9):

#### The issue

A script is not necessary.

The issue is not that a `.desktop` file cannot run commands with subshells, since

```bsh
Exec=/bin/bash -c "echo $(date) > ~/out.txt"
```

works perfectly fine in a `.desktop` file.

Fiddling around with the command, I came to the conclusion that the `%` -character is causing the issue. I have no explanation for it though, and so far I could not find information on how to solve or escape that.

I therefore went looking for a command to get the time *without* using the suspected character.

#### Alternatively use Ruby for the date & time

This lead me to `Ruby`, which produces the current date & time from the command:

```bsh
$ ruby -e 'puts Time.now.inspect'
2016-05-29 16:12:36 +0200
```

When we edit the output a bit with `awk`, removing spaces and delimiters, we have just what we want, ***and*** a working command in the `.desktop` file, since we don't use `%`:

```
Exec=/bin/bash -c  "gedit ~/$(ruby -e 'puts Time.now.inspect' | awk -F'[: -]' '{print $1$2$3$4$5$6}')"
```

[image]

#### Note!

No doubt, the command can be "charmed up" a bit, I will probably edit the answer a bit today or tomorrow.

Comment: Nice!  This is definitely another way to do it.  I didn't have Ruby installed but once it is installed, this definitely works.  I agree that fiddling with this you could get it to look the way you want it to be.  :)

Comment: @Terrance it turns out to be an interesting question. Never ran into an issue in `.desktop` files like this before...

Comment: Me neither.  It is good to know, and I have found that answering questions like these a lot of times we learn a lot ourselves as well.  :)

Comment: @Terrance 99% of what I know I learned on answering questions :)

Comment: You inspired me to change my wording in my answer as well.  I changed mine to be one way instead of the best way.  And other such changes so people don't think it is the only way.  Thank you!  :)

Comment: Maybe `.desktop` files can escape characters using a backslash (`+\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S`), or in this case, double percent (`+%%Y%%m%%d%%H%%M%%S`)

Comment: @BharadwajRaju Those were two of the many, many attempts I passed through today. I know that's how it is done from cron, but unfortunately it doesn't work here.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is first google result, let me link another answer that is way simpler:

[.desktop file with date variable not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/890853/desktop-file-with-date-variable-not-working)

In short:
'The freedesktop standard specifies that filetype arguments use % symbol, but can be escaped via double % sign.'

So instead of

```
Exec=gedit ~/$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).txt
```

use

```
Exec=gedit ~/$(date +%%Y%%m%%d%%H%%M%%S).txt
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the only correct answer on this page, accepted and other answers are workarounds.