# .desktop file with date variable not working

Tags: 14.04, bash, .desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=test
Exec=bash -c 'DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d) ; echo $DATE'
Terminal=true
Icon=utilities-terminal
```

when I double click it, nothing happen, and I don't want to wrap another script on it, what should I do to fix  this one-liner?

Comment: Try escaping the `%`, so it will be `%%Y%%m%%d`

Comment: Specifically, the freedesktop standard reserves `%` for special field codes such as `%F` (list of files to be passed to the application) and so on - see [The Exec key](https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As properly pointed out by steeldriver and muru, the freedesktop standard specifies that filetype arguments use `%` symbol, but can be escaped via double `%`  sign.

An additional issue in your program is that the default `gnome-terminal` will launch, but exit immediately once the child program exits. In your case, `bash -c` would exit once echo is complete. In order to hold terminal open, you need to add another shell call. In addition, you don't need to echo the variable, you can just use `date` directly. Thus your edited file would look like so:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=test
Exec=bash -c 'echo "TEST";date +%%Y%%m%%d;bash'
Terminal=true
Icon=utilities-terminal
```

As you can see in the screenshot, the second call to shell properly holds window open and displays the timestamp:

[image]

See also:

- https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html